# What is this bug, and how worried do I need to be?

Tags: identification, insects, bugs

This creature was on one of my tomato plants. I saw only the one. What is it, and do I need to be worried about it?

[image]

Comment: But two thumbs up for the _way better_ photo! Would you be ok with me copying it to the other question? For some reason this bug seems to have taken a liking to tomatoes this season...?

Comment: @Stephie Go right ahead.